# map xml to an object

Tags: xml, dictionary, object

Please help me to map such xml format to an objects

```
<Size name="Ident">
    <Number id="1">
      <Fol name="PASS">XXX</Fol>
    </Number>
    <Number id="2">
      <Fol name="PASS2">Error</Fol>
    </Number>
</Size>
```

Comment: Have you tried [lxml](https://lxml.de/)?

Comment: What object? What language?

Comment: Oh, @OldProgrammer, by looking at the tag `dictionary` I presumed `Python`! Good catch!

Comment: Hopefully, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66173031/parse-xml-dom-to-an-object    solve this problem also.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for an answer in the **Python** language, here it goes:

The [lxml](https://lxml.de/4.2/tutorial.html#tree-iteration) package let's you iterate over the elements of the xml in *depth first* manner, and you can print the tag name, it's attributes and and text associated with it.

```py
xml = r"""
<Size name="Ident">
    <Number id="1">
      <Fol name="PASS">XXX</Fol>
    </Number>
    <Number id="2">
      <Fol name="PASS2">Error</Fol>
    </Number>
</Size>
"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for element in root.iter():
    print('Tag Name: {}'.format(element.tag))
    print('Tag Attrib: {}'.format(element.attrib))
    print('Tag text (when available): {}'.format(element.text))
```

Will produce:

```sh
Tag Name: Size
Tag Attrib: {'name': 'Ident'}
Tag text (when available): 
    
Tag Name: Number
Tag Attrib: {'id': '1'}
Tag text (when available): 
      
Tag Name: Fol
Tag Attrib: {'name': 'PASS'}
Tag text (when available): XXX
Tag Name: Number
Tag Attrib: {'id': '2'}
Tag text (when available): 
      
Tag Name: Fol
Tag Attrib: {'name': 'PASS2'}
Tag text (when available): Error
```

Comment: `map such xml format to an objects`: once you have access to the data as shown above, you can put it in any data-structure of your choice.